# How to update parameter of a Crystal Report with Crystal Reports Server?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

We have Crystal Reports XI and are using Crystal Reports Server XI. We have many reports on Crystal Server but none are using report parameters.

I created a `.RPT` with 1 parameter called `REPORT_TYPE` that is a `STATIC` parameter in my report. For some reason, when I upload the report to Crystal Server, I cannot change the parameter value. I tried the following steps:

1. Opened the report in Crystal Server and clicked Process -> Parameters
2. Clicked where it displays the parameter named and [EMPTY] next to the value
3. I then can type any value I want in the field titled "Enter a value" but when I click update nothing happens. The page does not reload and the value is not stored in the report if I click another tab and go back it still displays [EMPTY]

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated! I tried using both the latest version of Chrome and IE (also with and without Computability View).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is modify the report on crystal and upload it again into the server. If you don't have the report, preview it and download a copy as crystal reports.

You can also do a repository connection. It will allow you to make changes on a report that is already on the server. In below link you can see how to make the connection.

[How to make repository connection with crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282596/how-to-make-repository-connection-with-crystal-report/26283205#26283205)

Comment: Thank you - I can upload multiple versions of the report with different parameters but shouldn't I be able to add additional Instances using different parameters? That way I can manage one report with the multiple parameters? Thanks!

Comment: what you are trying to do is add more values to that parameter?

Comment: What you can do on the server is default your parameter with a different value, but not modify it.

Comment: Thank you - how do I default the parameters to a different value on the server?

Comment: being on the server do a right click on the report, properties, prompts, edit values and set the one you want as default, but notice that this will work if you want to schedule that report to be auto delivery