# How to make repository connection with crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, progress-db

Added new column to table and print option.

How to connect existing crystal report with repository, i want to add new column in the rpt file.

Comment: which version of CR you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CR 13, you'll go to `View`, `Repository Explorer` and a windows will appears in the right side of your report. Then `Logon` in the top and another windows will comes up. There you will enter your BO address without http:// and your credentials. Then logon and all your repository and enterprise items will appear.